# Creating text files in a python script

Tags: python

I am making a project for a class in which the professor, like myself, has a pretty limited knowledge of how programming works. I created a script in Python that requires writing a new text file and I found that the program only functions correctly when run using IDLE or Python Launcher and will not create the text file when opened using Terminal. Is there any way to get this to work without having to download anything?

Edit:
This is the part of the code that creates the text file

```
text_file = open("text_file.txt", "w")
shuffle(chapters)
text_file.writelines(chapters)
```

It correctly creates the text file when I run it using eclipse, IDLE, and Python Launcher but I would like for my professor to be able to run it without downloading any of these

Comment: how are u running the file using terminal?

Comment: What does your python script look like?

Comment: What do you mean "opened using Terminal"? `python myfile.py`?

Comment: @user3078672 In order for us to help you, we'll need to see the code you're written. That ways, we can actually answer your question without having to resort to wild guesses.

Comment: @wheaties I've added the part of the code that creates the text file

Comment: Do you get any error messages (e.g. permissions, couldn't find file, ...)? Are you sure you're looking in the right place (working directory) for the new file?

Comment: @jonrsharpe There are no error messages when I run it using the python command in terminal. The GUI opens correctly but when I press the button to create the text file the new file is not created. Everything works as it should when I run it using eclipse, IDLE, and python launcher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your professor is running on Linux, Unix or Mac they you can just run the python file by a) ensuring it starts with a comment reading:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

and then setting the file as executable with `chmod +x scriptname.py`

If he/she is running on windows either he/she will have to install python, (then they can run the script from the command line or by double clicking on it), or you will have to convert it to an executable by using one of py2exe, pyinstaller, etc.

The other option is to download pocket python install it with your script on a usb key and run it that way.